# How do I access a facebook page's tabs data in the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tabs, facebook-page

According to the facebook developer's [article](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) on pages, pages have a tabs connection.  It says common tabs can be accessed by a plain text string.

When I try to access the tabs data on my page, an OAuthException error is flagged stating the subject must be a page.

Any ideas why my page is throwing this exception?

Page ID is:136789689670650

When I use the graph to query my information on the root, 136789689670650, my page information is pulled up.
When I use the graph to query my information on the tabs, 136789689670650/tabs/reviews, the exception is thrown.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do things in this order to access a pages tabs:

Send an HTTP GET to `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/accounts`, where user_id is the page owner. You can also do `/me/accounts` if it's your own page.

This will return a JSON data structure like this:

{
  data: [
    {
      name: "Page Name",
      access_token: "Page Access Token",
      category: "",
      id: "136789689670650",
    }
  ]
}

data is an array of all pages admin'd by that user. Each page has it's own access_token that you need to use for your next request.

Once you have the page access token you can send a request to `/136789689670650/tabs/reviews` using your page access token.

Comment: You can also retrieve a pages access_token as such now: `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID
  ?fields=access_token&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`